# pregmatch is not working PHP

Tags: php

I have this piece of code

```
if(preg_match('/zWi[a-zA-Z0-9]+TcH/', $cust_ref_no)) {
            echo "Im in";
        }
```

I have $cust_ref_no as 'zWijdGc83806161TcH'

This is not working.Any guess why?

Comment: works for me...test it here; http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Comment: `echo` out $cust_ref_no and cross check with the value u think it is. As everything seems to be right

Answer (score 0):

The regex is fine. $cust_ref_no must not be what you think it is, try echoing it prior to your preg_match.

Regex test:
http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=zWi%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2BTcH&input=zWijdGc83806161TcH

Answer (score 0):

The regex you wrote works for me like this:

```
$cust_ref_no = 'zWijdGc83806161TcH';
var_dump(preg_match('/zWi[a-zA-Z0-9]+TcH/', $cust_ref_no));
```

This leads me to believe the problem is not in the code you pasted. You should attempt to isolate the problem and make sure the `$cust_ref_no` variable contains what you think it contains, for example by placing a `var_dump` in front of this expression or setting up [xdebug for remote debugging](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote).